# Increase wireless reception with single network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I've got the following problem: For some reasons (maybe thick walls) my WLAN reception in one part of my flat is very poor.

I tried out a WLAN repeater but the problem is that it creates a second network and my devices sometimes are still connected to my original (shitty) one when walking around the flat.

I'd like to have a solution where I just have one single network. I've heard about Access Points...

In my case I have a network cable available. So is it possible to connect an access point or a router with my LAN cable to the network and use it as an extra antenna for spreading my one network?

And if so what device and which configuration do I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify some things. A consumer level router is two to three devices in one, a two port [router](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_%28computing%29) (one port exposed as the "WAN" port, one port connected to the switch), a [network switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch), and a sometimes a [wireless access point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point). So you have been using a wireless access point this whole time, you just did not know it.

If you have a spare wireless access point (and this could be one built in to a old router with all the features like DCHP turned off) all you need to do is connect your network like this

```
Internet -------- (WAN port)[Router with built in access point](LAN Port) ------------ (LAN PORT)[stand alone access point(or a 2nd router with built in or access point)]
```

You then set both routers to the same [SSID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_%28802.11_network%29) but set them on [different channels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels) (keep them 5 away from each other for best performance, like channel 1 and 6). Your computer should automatically hop on to the strongest access point it can find transparently.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the best discussions about the different wireless router linking methods [DD-Wrt Linking Router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linking_Routers)
Be aware that each mode support depends of your router firmware. I'm currently using WDS to do just what you want to do but without an UTP linking both routers. I have yet to confirm if the same SSID can be configured on bouth wireless routers